# PHP - Extending package model to your own

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently trying to setup a simple web-app, using [Laravel Mailbox](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-mailbox).  I can see that I can define a custom model to use in the config file:

```
    /*
     * The model class to use when converting an incoming email to a message.
     * It must extend the default model class
     */
    'model' => \BeyondCode\Mailbox\InboundEmail::class,
```

Above is the default model it uses.

I have changed it to:

```
    /*
     * The model class to use when converting an incoming email to a message.
     * It must extend the default model class
     */
    'model' => Email::class,
```

Now, I wish to use my own model, because I want to store the e-mails on another table. For this, I have created my own model, and trying to extend the original one from the package, but overwrite the `$table` for example.

App/Email.php:

```
namespace App;

use BeyondCode\Mailbox\InboundEmail as InboundEmail;

class Email extends InboundEmail
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
    }

    protected $table = 'emails';
}
```

However, above gives me below error:

```
Undefined property: App\Email::$message {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined property: App\\Email::$message at /Users/Username/Sites/playground/vendor/beyondcode/laravel-mailbox/src/InboundEmail.php:130)
```

I suspect it is because I don't have the original methods in my own model `App/Email.php`, that are present in the package model.

Isn't there a way that I can use my own model, by extending the package model, but without copying the content of the package model into my own?

Comment: What model does InboundEmail extends?

Comment: It extends the “normal” Laravel `Model` class

Comment: Where is the code that triggers the error? It seems like the mail messages get not injected in correctly

Comment: The code gets triggered by a 3rd party API, that basically just send the request containing the email, to my server. If I use the default model above, the code runs fine.